# Main.this having problems fixing this

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to do a sample project but I am having errors. I'm extremely new to app development 2 days to be exact but not new to IT. I'm following a tutorial but the version of eclipse and ADT the instructor is using is pretty old and different.

For the most part I am able to get around it because of my experience with programming, but I am not able to past this and I need to before I move on, the error message is this

"main cannot be resolved to a type"

```
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(main.this, second.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The thing is the instructor did exactly the same and no problems, i'm thinking it has to do something with the older version he's using.

Help anyone?

Thanks

Comment: It is nothing to do with the version.  This code will not work on any version.  There is no variable in scope called `main`.  Either you have left something out, or the code in the tutorial is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

try `MainActivity.this` instead of `main.this`

`this` is a Java keyword indicateing the current object. In your case, `this` refers to `OnClickListener` instanace. But you really wanted to refer to the Activity class instance. To refer to the outer class it would be `MainActivity.this`